# How can I get the blob URL after a file upload to Azure from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I uploaded a file to my blob storage in Azure and now I want to get the Azure link for the upload. I'm using node.js and below is my code:

```
blobService.createContainerIfNotExists('trimfaces', {
  publicAccessLevel: 'blob'
}, function(error, result, response) {
  if (!error) {
    // if result = true, container was created.
    // if result = false, container already existed.
  }
});
```

Comment: The link is like this `http://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<blob-name> `

Comment: Your code isn't showing how you uploaded your blob. Did you write code to do so, or are you talking about manually uploading  blobs and then finding them programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to call `blobService.getUrl(containerName, blobName)`. The API document is here: http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#getUrl

[Updated]

The versioned document for v10 or later is at:
https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/javascript/azure-storage-blob/12.0.0/classes/blockblobclient.html#url

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, this is the way to list blobs using node:

```
blobSvc.listBlobsSegmented('mycontainer', null, function(error, result, response){
  if(!error){
    // result.entries contains the entries
    // If not all blobs were returned, result.continuationToken has the continuation token.
  }
});
```

You can see the entire documentation for Azure Storage Blobs here: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage/